# C++ running structure in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have two files in the same project, which are `f1.cpp` and `f2.cpp` used to solve the same problem "connectivity problem" in algorithm. In visual studio I put them into the sources files.Another file in the source files is `pch.cpp`. Also the project name is `f1`.

The code of f1.cpp is,

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static const int N = 10000;

int main()
{
    int i, p, q, id[N];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) id[i] = i;
    while (cin >> p >> q) {
        int t = id[p];
        if (t == id[q]) continue;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            // this is for union 
            if (id[i] == t) id[i] = id[q];
        cout << " " << p << " " << q << endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
    return 0;
}
```

the f2.cpp is,

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pch.h"

using namespace std;

static const int N = 10000;
int main() {
    int i, j, p, q, id[N], sz[N];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) { id[i] = i, sz[i] = 1; }
    while (cin >> p >> q) {
        for (i = p; i != id[i]; i = id[i]);
        for (j = q; j != id[j]; j = id[j]);
        if (i == j) continue;
        if (sz[i] < sz[j]) {
            id[i] = j; sz[j] += sz[i];
        }
        else {
            id[j] = i; sz[i] += sz[j];
        }
        cout << " " << p << " " << q << endl;
    }
}
```

Although I am pretty sure the two codes, if run independently, is no error. But as they appear together in the sources files, when I ran the f2.cpp, there will be error as

> C2065 'cin': undeclared identifier    connectivity problem
>   C2065 'cout': undeclared identifier   connectivity problem
>   C2065 'endl': undeclared identifier   connectivity problem

```
My question is why the error like this happens ? 
Do I have to open a new project in visual studio for editing different solutions on same problems ?
```

Comment: If you run them together, the linker will produce **two `main()` methods**, and that will cause a compiler error since you can have only one `main()`...

Comment: Can I run them separately in the same project ?

Comment: Remove the file ... so I need to open a new project to run them separately ?

Comment: @exteralvictor si, senor!

Comment: @exteralvictor Or you just have to use defines in your code...

Comment: if I use define, I also need to remove the main() right ?

Comment: @exteralvictor Nope, look at my answer...

Comment: If `pch.h` represent a precompiled header, it should be include in a give cpp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like I pointed out before if you run multiple source files together, the linker will produce two `main()` methods, and that will cause a compiler error since you can have only one `main()`...

Remember that the program can only point to one `main()` function...

**But, you *can* use `#define`s in your code:**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static const int N = 10000;

// Running the first project...
#define F_PROJ

// Psuedo main for first project...
int first_main()
{
    int i, p, q, id[N];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) id[i] = i;
    while (cin >> p >> q) {
        int t = id[p];
        if (t == id[q]) continue;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            // this is for union 
            if (id[i] == t) id[i] = id[q];
        cout << " " << p << " " << q << endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}

// Psuedo main for second project...
int second_main()
{
    int i, j, p, q, id[N], sz[N];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) { id[i] = i, sz[i] = 1; }
    while (cin >> p >> q) {
        for (i = p; i != id[i]; i = id[i]);
        for (j = q; j != id[j]; j = id[j]);
        if (i == j) continue;
        if (sz[i] < sz[j]) {
            id[i] = j; sz[j] += sz[i];
        }
        else {
            id[j] = i; sz[i] += sz[j];
        }
        cout << " " << p << " " << q << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
#ifdef F_PROJ
    first_main();
#elif defined(S_PROJ)
    second_main();
#endif
}
```

Just point `#define F_PROJ` or `#define S_PROJ` respectively...

Comment: It would be a lot cleaner to put them into separate functions and pick one based on a command line argument or something along those lines.

Comment: Great that would be a thought.